# What is the best way to position these elements in this specific design?

Tags: html, css

Here is where my code is now:

[link](https://preview.c9users.io/devonte202/who-are-we/WhoWeArePage.html?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io)

Here is the design I am trying to achieve:

[Picture of design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM2Wt.png)

I've tried position relative and margins however the methods I've used ended up compromising the responsiveness of my page. What is the best way to position these elements in the above design while still keeping the webpage able to adapt to a change in screen size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap for getting responsive designs. When you use bootstrap you can use the grid system to manage your elements. class "row" will get you a grid divided into 12 equal columns. You can then use col-md-x/col-sm-x depending on you design to position your elements. You can refer to http://getbootstrap.com/css/ to learn further. In other word use col-md-3 to display image and col-md-9 for information. It will work.

Example just for reference:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <img /> <-- put your image here -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-9">
       <-- put your texthere -->
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-9">
       <-- put your texthere -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <img /> <-- put your image here -->           
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Random plugging of Bootstrap isn't an answer to their questions. Come on now.

Comment: @JBartus: I don't agree. It is easier to acheive RWD when you use such predefined CSS rather than trying to code evrything yourself. Cleaner view with less efforts!!

Comment: No matter how you cut it saying 'just use Bootstrap' is a massive cop out. If you code up an example of what they're trying to do in Bootstrap to demonstrate it to them I wouldn't be saying this but all you did was point them at Bootstrap and walk away.

Comment: @JBartus: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added an example for reference.

Comment: You would be better served to order the divs with the images in the same manner and use column offsets so that you have consistent presentation on mobile and screen-readers.